# Is it possible to change interface language to Hebrew?

Tags: languages, user-interface, hebrew

Is it possible to change the GUI language to Hebrew in an Amazon Fire 7/8/10 tablet? To clarify - not the input (keyboard) language, but the interface itself.

[I am assuming Fire OS questions fit in this forum. If you think there is a better place to ask, please let me know]

Comment: If Hebrew is listed in your Language and Input settings, you can. Mostly devices manufactured in/for a specific country contain local languages. Imported devices don't.

Comment: @IrfanLatif - Thanks. The device will be purchased in the US for Hebrew-reading users. I can't tell if there is such option in the menu, b/c... I did not buy the thing yet. Just want to make sure it will provide the option (as a cheaper alternative to a native Android tablet).